# Non-void methods in base class cannot access all methods in member class

Tags: c++

I have a class `TCPReceiver` having as a private member an instance of a class `StreamReassembler`. When trying to access a method within `StreamReassembler` i noticed that outside of a void function i do not have access to all methods within `StreamReassembler`.

Implementation of `StreamReassembler`:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class StreamReassembler {
private:
    size_t _capacity; 
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, size_t>> storedInMemory;
    size_t lastByteWritten;
    size_t segmentSize;

public:
    StreamReassembler(const size_t capacity);

    bool allowWritingToBuffer(const std::string &segment) const;

    size_t freeMemory();

    size_t getLastByteWritten();

    size_t unassembled_bytes() const;

    bool empty() const;
};
```

Source file:

```
#include "stream_reassembler.hh"

using namespace std;

StreamReassembler::StreamReassembler(const size_t capa)
    : _output(capa), _capacity(capa), storedInMemory(0), lastByteWritten(0), segmentSize(0) {}

void StreamReassembler::push_substring(const string &data, const size_t index, const bool eof) {
    segmentSize = sizeof(data);

    if (index == lastByteWritten + 1) {    // if current received segment is next in order
        if (allowWritingToBuffer(data)) {  // check if there's enough space on buffer to write segment
            _output.write(data);
            lastByteWritten += segmentSize;  // update lastByteWritten to check next segment
        }
    } else {
        if (segmentSize <= freeMemory()) {  // make sure capacity is not exceeded
            storedInMemory.emplace_back(std::make_pair(data, index));
        }
    }

    if (segmentSize > freeMemory() or eof) {
        std::sort(storedInMemory.begin(),
                  storedInMemory.end(),
                  [](std::pair<std::string, size_t> &rhs, std::pair<std::string, size_t> &lhs) {
                      return rhs.second > lhs.second;
                  });

        for (const auto & segment : storedInMemory){
            _output.write(segment.first);
        }
        lastByteWritten = index + segmentSize;
    }
}

size_t StreamReassembler::unassembled_bytes() const { return storedInMemory.size() * sizeof(storedInMemory[0].first); }

bool StreamReassembler::empty() const { return storedInMemory.empty(); }

bool StreamReassembler::allowWritingToBuffer(const std::string &segment) const {
    return sizeof(segment) >= _output.remaining_capacity();
}

size_t StreamReassembler::freeMemory() { return _capacity - unassembled_bytes() - _output.buffer_size(); }

size_t StreamReassembler::getLastByteWritten() {return lastByteWritten;}
```

The class in which i have problems accessing methods:

```
#include "stream_reassembler.hh"
#include <optional>

class TCPReceiver {

    StreamReassembler _reassembler;
    size_t _capacity;

  public:
    
    TCPReceiver(const size_t capacity) : _reassembler(capacity), _capacity(capacity) {}

    std::optional<WrappingInt32> ackno() const;

    size_t window_size() const;

    size_t unassembled_bytes() const { return _reassembler.unassembled_bytes(); }

    void segment_received(const TCPSegment &seg);
};
```

```
#include "tcp_receiver.hh"

using namespace std;

void TCPReceiver::segment_received(const TCPSegment &seg) {
    _reassembler.getLastByteWritten(); //working
}

optional<WrappingInt32> TCPReceiver::ackno() const {
    // last byte + 1
    _reassembler.getLastByteWritten(); //not working
}


size_t TCPReceiver::window_size() const { return _capacity - _reassembler.stream_out().buffer_size(); }
```

Example that works fine:

```
void TCPReceiver::segment_received(const TCPSegment &seg) {
    _reassembler.getLastByteWritten();
}
```

I get the following error: `'this' argument to member function 'getLastByteWritten' has type 'const StreamReassembler', but function is not marked const`

```
optional<WrappingInt32> TCPReceiver::ackno() const {
    // last byte + 1
    _reassembler.getLastByteWritten();
}
```

Comment: Could you show a [mcve] that shows exactly what you’re writing and what errors you get?

Comment: which ide you are using?

Comment: You haven't accidentally written implementations of `windowSize`, `unassembledBytes` and `ackno` that are free functions rather than members of `TCPReceiver`?

Comment: @UmarFarooq Isn't the compiler more essential than the IDE OP is using? Btw. this is something which should work properly in any C++ compiler (if done right).

Comment: @Scheff i don't see a problem but often i face it cause of ide bug and many of the people including me use to think something is wrong with my code , that's why asked what ide he is using cause in clion it is common.

Comment: @G.M. no, i declared them in the header file and was defining them in the source file.
 I am using CLion 2020. Will add photos, maybe those help.

Comment: @beginner420 Re. `"Will add photos"`: no, please add the code as correctly formatted text.

Comment: No photos please. Instead please provide a [mre] and quote all messages you receive while building, verbatim, in full, as text and directly here. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7733418

Comment: _i do not have access to all methods_ It couldn't hurt to [edit] your question and copy/paste the literal error messages (as text, of course). (Not that you are hunting wrong IntelliSense remarks as suspected by @UmarFarooq.)

Comment: @Yunnosch I was in good hope as OP is at least reacting with not so long delay. ;-)

Comment: @Scheff Me too, I am for patience. But I think the MRE concept did not get through and instead mentioning it triggered the picture offer. Careful reading and applying is needed.

Comment: beginner420 Thanks for the improved code (and not as picture ;-) ). Please also add quotes of the build messages you get.

Comment: Please, read again about [mcve]. A [mcve] is something I can copy/paste e.g. into an online compiler to reproduce your issue personally. With your exposed declarations, this is not possible, isn't it?

Comment: Reading (even the improved) code, I doubt it is a [mre]. I expect problems with `TCPSegment ` for example.

Comment: Isn't there a `return` missing in your last snippet?

Comment: Meanwhile I was able to reproduce your issue: [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e62ea3f601cede23)

Comment: @Scheff i mistakenly forgot it but still doesn't work. Same error. Have also added source files.

Comment: The reason is simple: If you call a non-const function in a const function, you get this error. The solution is probably to declare `TCPReceiver::ackno()` as non-const as well. (Makes sense to me - it changes the internal state of `TCPReceiver`.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the rapid responses. Did not know this could be an issue so i just declared it const.

Comment: plus you need to change your return datatype you std::optional will not accept unsigned long

Comment: A bit lengthy now, but you have my reopen-vote. Consider trying harder in the future for a more [mre].

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to call a non-const function from a const function. Your error says so. Either your calling function needs to be non-const, or the receiving function needs to be const.

More specifically, your member variable may be mutated from the call to your const method.